# is there a way to bind parameter to a function variable in python?

Tags: python

Consider the following example:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print ("Constructor")
    def testMethod(self,val):
        print ("Hello " + val)
    def test(self):
        ptr = self.testMethod("Joe") <---- Anyway instead of calling self.testMethod with parameter "Joe" I could simple bind the parameter Joe to a variable ?
        ptr()

k = foo()
k.test()
```

In the defintion `test` is it possible for me to create a variable which when called calls the method `self.testMethod` with the parameter `"Joe"` ?

Comment: Why is this a downvote now ? Anyway i could improve this ? Downvoting without a clue isnt really productive

Comment: You mean something like: `def test(self, name):  ptr=self.testMethod(name)`  ? Then you can call k.test("Joe")

Comment: You mean like `from functools import partial`, then `self.callable = partial(self.testMethod, 'Joe')`?

Comment: yes partial is what I am looking equivalent to std::bind in C++

Comment: I would love to know why someone gave me a downvote though on a totally logical question

Comment: Not my downvote, but insofar as the problem appears to have only come up in the first place on account of searching the docs using C++ terminology ("binder") instead of functional programming terminology ("partial"), I could see someone from the FP world being annoyed at it. But I think that makes it a good and useful question even as a duplicate; not everyone _does_ know functional terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or a `lambda` expression:

```
from functools import partial

ptr = partial(self.testMethod, 'Joe')
```

or

```
ptr = lambda: self.testMethod('Joe')
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for thank you. Marked as the answer

Comment: It appears you marked the *other* answer, actually. That's your choice entirely but your comment is confusing in that case :-)

Comment: Sorry abt that. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a name to the constructor (and store it on the class instance), this is then accessible to methods:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("Constructor")
        self.name = name

    def testMethod(self):
        print("Hello " + self.name)

    def test(self):
        self.testMethod()
```

As follows:

```
k = Foo("Joe")
k.test()          # prints: Hello Joe
```

Comment: Not really. I am looking for binding functionality. I dont want any other approach. The code i just posted is a simple example.